# AngularJs filtering on click using a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I am trying to filter a list in using a click event in custom directive the filter works fine but how do I assign the filtered items so it is reflected in ng-repeat? Right now the list generated using ng-repeat on quesCompletedHeaders is not changed after the click event has taken place

```
app.directive('sectionSelector', ['$filter', 'questionnaireSections',
  function ($filter, questionnaireSections) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        iElement.on('click', function () {
          scope.$apply(function () {

            // filters correct question range 
            var filtered = $filter('rangeFilter')(scope.quesCompletedHeaders, [5, 10], true);
            console.log(filtered); //=> This is correct how to put back on scope?

            // There is an ng-repeat on quesCompletedHeaders in the template
            // but nothing changes even when assigning filted results back
            // on scope
            scope.quesCompletedHeaders = filtered;

            // works with $parent not sure why a child scope is 
            // created with the directive
            scope.$parent.quesCompletedHeaders = filtered
          });

        });
      }

    };
  }
]);
```

Ok I found out the reason sectionSelector is creating a child scope which should not be since scope:false is the default?  why is this happening?
using  scope.$parent.quesCompletedHeaders = filtered; solves the issue

Comment: Can you show some html structure where this directive is used and relationship to the ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0):

Add scope 'quesCompletedHeaders' to directive

HTML

```
<hello-world sectionSelector="filtered.quesCompletedHeaders"></hello-world>
```

Javascript

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.filtered.quesCompletedHeaders = {};
});


app.directive('sectionSelector', ['$filter', 'questionnaireSections',
function ($filter, questionnaireSections) {
return {
  restrict: 'EA',
  scope: {
            questionnaireSections: "=",
        },
  link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
    iElement.on('click', function () {
      scope.$apply(function () {

        // filters correct question range 
        var filtered = $filter('rangeFilter')(scope.quesCompletedHeaders, [5, 10], true);
        console.log(filtered); 
        scope.filtered.quesCompletedHeaders = filtered;
      });

    });
  }

};
}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy alternative instead of directive.

you can have ng-click on the element and apply filter in controller to the list.

In HTML,

```
<input type="button" value="select section" ng-click="filterquestionaire(5,10)"/>
```

in Controller,

```
$scope.filterquestionaire = function(start,end) {
       var filtered = $filter('rangeFilter')(scope.quesCompletedHeaders, [start, end], true);
       $scope.quesCompletedHeaders = filtered;
};
```

Comment: There is a problem with this approach,    $scope.quesCompletedHeaders is now reduced so I wont be able to filter by says [11,15]  afterwards

Answer (score 0):

OK so here is my final solution.

```
$scope.rangeFilter = function (range) {
  $scope.quesRangeStart = range[0];
  $scope.quesRangeEnd = range[1];
}
```

In the template I am piping the filter

```
ng-repeat="question in quesCompletedHeaders|rangeFilter:[quesRangeStart, quesRangeEnd]"
```

and on the filter buttons

```
ng-repeat="section in questionnaireSections" 
ng-click="rangeFilter(section.range)"
```

and filter code

```
app.filter('rangeFilter', function () {
  return function (items, rangeInfo) {

    var min = parseInt(rangeInfo[0]);
    var max = parseInt(rangeInfo[1]);
    var filtered = items.filter(function (header) {
      return header.rang >= min && header.rang <= max;
    });

    return filtered;
  };
});
```